# Download sqlite database from Dropbox

Tags: iphone, xcode, dropbox

I am trying to download an sqlite database from my Dropbox using a direct link as the source path, and then saving it to the app's document file. It's just a means of updating the database without having to update the app.

When I check if the file exists before downloading, the file is not visible.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *sourceDBPath = @"https://www.dropbox.com/s/868vvg7uremst9n/Data.sqlite?dl=1";

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:sourceDBPath])
{

NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/868vvg7uremst9n/Data.sqlite?dl=1"]];

NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];


[dbFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Would I need to integrate the Dropbox SDK into my app even if I am using a direct link to the file?

Comment: I would think that if you can't download the sqlite database via a direct link (in your Safari browser), it won't be available as something you can download within your app.

Comment: Just to clarify: One can send a direct link to a file in your Dropbox via email to someone else and by simply clicking on the link the file can be made visble or ready for direct download (with ?dl=1 added to the link). So files can be seen or downloaded on a computer, but it does not seem to work within xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the link is definitely working, and no, you don't need to link up Dropbox and your app for this to work.

There are some issues with https and ios detailed here:

iOS 5's TLS implementation has been upgraded to support TLS protocol version 1.2. Some non-compliant TLS server implementations do not implement TLS 1.2 and, more importantly, do not downgrade gracefully to a supported protocol version. As a result you may find that some TLS client applications built against the iOS 5 SDK may not connect to some TLS servers, when the same application built against a previous version of the iOS SDK would connect.

[Excerpted from...](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2287/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011309)

## Update.

However, I just tried to  retrieve it using the following code:

```
NSString *dropboxHttpsUrl = @"https://www.dropbox.com/s/868vvg7uremst9n/Data.sqlite?dl=1";
NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                      [NSURL URLWithString:dropboxHttpsUrl]];

if(dbFile) {
   NSLog(@"%i", [dbFile length]);
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];
   [dbFile writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
   NSLog(@"%@", appFile);
}else{
   NSLog(@"nothing got retrieved");
}
```

And I was able to grab the database and see the empty `Example` table and schema.

Just build you document path in a more standard fashion:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];
```

Don't do:

```
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
```

It's this that's probably saving it to the wrong place, or worse not at all.

Comment: I think you have a good point, this may be the problem. I read the work around and inserted the recommended code just before attempting to read the Dropbox file, but there seems to be an issue with "myStream" that's not defined. It seems like I need to have a completely different method of reading the data from the Dropbox file (not using NSData). Can you give me any advice on how to read the file?

Comment: Many thanks, that seems to be a viable solution. I'm in transit at the moment so will give it more attention in the next day or so.

Comment: Well, you don't need all those alert views, and other than that, it seems pretty similar to yours.

Comment: I tried out your code but can't seem to get PSPDFAlertView to work. I managed to find PSPDFAlertView.h and PSPDFAlertView.m on the web, but still missing UIColor+PSPDFKitAdditions.h and it seems like I need the complete PSPDFKit Framework. Any suggestions on how to get PSPDFAlertView to work on IOS 6 ?

Comment: I've pulled out the PSPDF stuff, don't be distracted by it, you're meant to just pull out the useful code, and see that it's essentially the same as yours, just double check you're creating the document path properly.

Comment: Fair enough, got my code (and yours - thank you) to download the database file from my dropbox, but the saved failed in the app documents folder is not recognised as a database file after being saved. When I try to open it with an sqlite manager it now requires a password  - corrupted somehow?

Comment: I've opened it here, no problems using the code I've posted. The only issue you may of had was probably just losing the file's location, due to the way you were constructing the path/filename. (1) are you trying both the db file from Dropbox and the copy you're getting via iOS? ... and to avoid crap tool issues, just open it with sqlite3 on the command line. `sqlite3 test.db` type `.tables` in sqlite3.

Comment: Hi Slomojo, many thanks for your input, your code is spot on. I was in China when trying it a few days ago, and seems like direct links don't work the same there. Most of the time the direct link would not work (time out), and when it did the file got corrupted somehow. Anyhow I'm back home now and it works perfectly - thanks again.

Comment: ahh, yes, it's all going through the great firewall, bit of a key detail. ;)